# Build number/fingerprint for Android Things

Tags: adb, android-things, build-numbers

I'm using the *Developer Preview* of *Android Things* on my *Raspberry Pi 3* and now, that the *Preview 2* is released, I was asking myself if my RPi will get this via OTA.

Where can I find the build number to check against my device

```
generic/iot_rpi3/rpi3:7.0/NIF73/3565696:userdebug/test-keys
```

On the developer page I didn't find anything and before I rebuild by sdcard, it would be easier to compare it.

Comment: The Release Notes page lists the build numbers for each preview release. You are probably better off checking those against `ro.build.id` than looking at the full fingerprint (although the build number is embedded in there): https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I'm not sure if this is preview 1 or 2

`generic/iot_rpi3/rpi3:7.0/NIF73/3565696:userdebug/test-keys` is the fingerprint for *Preview 1*, so you're still on it.

You can

- `getprop ro.build.id` to see the build number which is also reflected on the [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html) (the hint came from [@Devunwired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246461/devunwired), so don't forget to upvote [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329683/build-number-fingerprint-for-android-things/42331834#comment-71826136))
- `getprop ro.build.date` to see the date of a build. *Preview 2* should give you February 2017 instead of December 2016 for *Preview 1*.