# android things 0.5.1-devpreview soft keyboard

Tags: keyboard, adb, android-softkeyboard, android-things

Android Things 0.5.1-devpreview installed on NXP Pico i.MX7D.

Cannot get the software keyboard to show.

```
adb -s <device> shell ime list -a
```

nothing shows

```
imx7d_pico:/ $ ime list -a | grep mId
```

nothing shows

```
ime enable com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
```

Error: Unknown id: null

```
am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$SystemDashboardActivity
```

no ime keyboards to manage

**Do I need to install a soft keyboard? How do I install a ime soft keyboard?**

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033832/6950238) answer of [Onik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3290339/onik)?

Comment: This is a [bug](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+CarlWhalley/posts/X3KnPu3JVGe?cfem=1) in Developer Preview 5.1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.... any timing on the fix?

Comment: Looking at the command results makes me think there is no Google keyboard app in the system. And since the keyboard app comes pre-installed starting with Android Things DP 4 it looks like you're running the version prior DP 4. Any chance flashing SD card failed? [Check the OS version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42329683/3290339).