# Check if an NXP iMX 8M has Android Things flashed?

Tags: android-things, nxp-microcontroller, cortex-a

Is is possible to check if my `NXP iMX 8M Cortex A53 + M4` already has *Android Things* flashed on it?

Or do I need to explicitly flash it on the hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NXP i.MX 8M` isn't currently [supported by *Android Things*](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms), only `NXP Pico i.MX7D`.

Comment: Thanks :( Is there any other tool/platform that can help me run a sample IoT application on NXP i.MX 8M? Also, is there a way to check if Android things is flashed, if we check on MX7D?

Comment: @user2176576, since `NXP i.MX7D` [supports  ADB over USB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44241668/3290339), you might try to connect to the hardware and [check the build info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42329683/3290339).